# What is the correct variable scope for this Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript

I have written the function below. I need to read the dimensions of an image and then scale it back. After the initial callback I want to use the `width` and `height` values I've calculated to resize and save the image. My variables are out of scope though and I get a `ReferenceError: width is not defined`. How do I correctly scope these variables so they are available to the `resize` function?

```
  function saveImage(image) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gm(image.data).size(function(error, value) {
        if (value.width > image.maxSize || value.height > image.maxSize) {
          max = Math.max(value.width, value.height);
          if (value.width == max) {
            width = image.maxSize; height = null;
          } else {
            height = image.maxSize; width = null;
          }
        } else {
          width = value.width; height = value.height;
        }
      })
      .resize(width, height)
      .write('./tmp/test.jpg', function(error, value) {
        if (!error) console.log(error);
      });;
    });
  }
```

Comment: where are `width` and `height` defined? I'd expect to see `var width...` etc somewhere, currently when you reference them, they don't exist

Comment: @sauntimo Unless they're being defined without using `var` inside the if.

Answer (score 1):

you should define your variable properly ...i prefer u should learn about es6 syntax and use "let" and "const" for variable and there scope is in wide range thank you:-@ravi

Answer (score 0):

In the promise you use an arrow function, but in the `.size()` line below you use an old style anonymous function, and then you lose your scope. You can try using arrow function for `.size()`

```
.size((error, value) => {})
```